# Leaflet open multiple popups without binding to a marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am busy writing a simple map implementation using leaflet however I have hit a bit of a snag. I am trying to setup my map and have added a custom control to show labels (which will show the popups) based on the selection of a checkbox.

My custom control is like so:

> ```
>         var checkBoxControl = L.Control.extend({
>             options: {
>                 position: 'topright'
>             },
>             onAdd: function (map) {
>                 var container = L.DomUtil.create('input', 'leaflet-control');
>
>                 container.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
>                 container.id = 'labels_checkbox';
>                 container.style.width = '30px';
>                 container.style.height = '30px';
>                 container.label = "Labels";
>                 container.type = 'checkbox';
>
>                 container.onclick = function () {
>                     var checkBox =  $("#labels_checkbox");
>                     var checkBoxValue = checkBox[0];
>                     var labelsChecked = checkBoxValue.checked;
>                     var bounds = mymap.getBounds();
>
>                     for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
>                         marker = markers[i].mark;
>
>                         if (bounds.contains(marker.getLatLng())) {
>                             var previewLabel = markers[i].previewLabel;
>                             if (labelsChecked == true) {
>                                 console.log('previewLabel', previewLabel);
>                                 mymap.addLayer(previewLabel).fire('popupopen');
>                             } else {
>                                 previewLabel.close();
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>
>                 };
>                 return container;
>             }
>         });
> ```

I can see as per my console that it is fetching all the surrounding markers however the map won't open those markers?

Is there a way for me to open a popup without binding it to a marker?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change L.Map behaviour to prevent automatic closing of popups.
It is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654126/leafletjs-marker-bindpopup-keep-all-popups-open).

```
  // prevent a popup to close when another is open
  L.Map = L.Map.extend({
  openPopup: function (popup, latlng, options) { 
      if (!(popup instanceof L.Popup)) {
      var content = popup;

      popup = new L.Popup(options).setContent(content);
      }

      if (latlng) {
      popup.setLatLng(latlng);
      }

      if (this.hasLayer(popup)) {
      return this;
      }

      // NOTE THIS LINE : COMMENTING OUT THE CLOSEPOPUP CALL
      //this.closePopup(); 
      this._popup = popup;
      return this.addLayer(popup);        
  }
});
```

See this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CAjJvltFrRgAWvHew8fx?p=previewhttp://)