# Open several popups at the same time

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Inside a jquery $.getJSON call, I create several markers and popups, then bind the popups to the markers:

```
$.each(points, function(index, p) {
   var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(p.lat, p.lon), { title: p.text });
   var popup = L.popup().setContent(p.text);
   marker.bindPopup(popup);
}
```

I want all popups on the markers to be open after the map has loaded (and stay open, if possible). The Leaflet 1.0 documentation states: " Use Map.openPopup ... or use Map.addLayer to open as many as you want." (see [leaflet -  popup](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-methods-for-layers-and-controls)).

If possible, I would prefer using a "built in" solution to one where I have to fiddle around (like in [SO - keep popups open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654126/leafletjs-marker-bindpopup-keep-all-popups-open)). One advantage is that that approach can be generically used, for example to open all tooltips as well. And it would probably help me understand layers better.

I have tried several approaches, with LayerGroups and FeatureGroups, to no avail. How would you open a group of popups at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a layerGroup containing all your popups. That way you have all the functionalities of group control for your popups.

I reproduced a basic example on JSfidle (https://jsfiddle.net/vaillant/f4zpr6us/) but you can imagine removing only certain popups from the layerGroup instead of removing all the popups at once. Below is the crucial part of the code:

```
var popup_layer = new L.layerGroup();

$.each(testData, function(index, p) {
   var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(p.lat, p.lon));
   marker.addTo(map);
   popup = new L.popup({offset:  new L.Point(0, -30)});
   popup.setLatLng(L.latLng(p.lat, p.lon));
   popup.setContent(p.text);
   popup.openPopup();
   popup_layer.addLayer(popup);
});

popup_layer.addTo(map);
```