# Cannot assign to XX because it is a read-only property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using leaflet library. There i am having problem with my pop up, and there is not out of the box option to prevent pop up from closing in some situations so i want to edit the library where their code says so - to comment that piece of line and to solve my problem [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654126/leafletjs-marker-bindpopup-keep-all-popups-open).

The problem is, when I try his suggestion in my ngOnInit method:

```
L.Map = L.Map.include({
  openPopup: function (popup, latlng, options) {
    if (!(popup instanceof L.Popup)) {
      var content = popup;

      popup = new L.Popup(options).setContent(content);
    }

    if (latlng) {
      popup.setLatLng(latlng);
    }

    if (this.hasLayer(popup)) {
      return this;
    }

    // NOTE THIS LINE : COMMENTING OUT THE CLOSEPOPUP CALL
    //this.closePopup();
    this._popup = popup;
    return this.addLayer(popup);
  },
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot assign to 'Map' because it is a read-only property.
```

How can I solve this? In JavaScript it works this way (see http://jsfiddle.net/yVLJf/37/), but in Angular/TypeScript this error pops up.

Comment: Use arrow function inside object so that it will point to current this object.

Comment: I have another problem.I have compilation error regarding the read only property of the library it self.